# Selecting 1 word out of a field using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I need to extract "SRN=123"  (the 123 is dynamic in length, SRN= is consistent) from a column.  Data could be anything, no consistent format

> 456 lorem limpsump SRN=123 and some
>   more things 3.

I'm having trouble trying to use a charindex to find the ending point of SRN=123 to get the length, any help?

```
SUBSTRING(t.Instructions, 
                             CharIndex('SRN=', t.Instructions) + 10, 
                             (CHARINDEX('SRN=', t.Instructions )-(CharIndex('SRN=[^0-9.-]', t.Instructions) + 10)))
```

Comment: Which sql are you referring to?  The answer may change based on what you're using (oracle, msql, etc.)

Comment: If the 123 portion is a dynamic length, is there any indicator for the end of the string you need to get? Will there always be a space at the end of of the SRN=xxxxxx portion?  Can the substring itself contain spaces?

Comment: Looks like you are using SQL Server and if it is 2005 or above best bet would be ti use regular expresisons via CLR UDF to extract the data.. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx#S1

Comment: You can easily find where SRN= begins, but if the number to the right of the = sign is variable length, how do you know when it ends? Does the number contain any white-space? Is it numeric or alphanumeric? When you say "Data could be anything" are you referring to the value to the right of the = sign?

Comment: Using SQL 2008, SRN=XXXX, xxx will always be numbers, it could have a whitespace after or it might be the end of the field

Comment: Can the number contain whitespace? E.g. SRN=145 X22 or SRN=Jaguar XJ6 or SRN= 123. That last example has a leading space. The first two have embedded space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 'SRN='+left(stuff(@S, 1, charindex('SRN=', @S)+3, ''), patindex('%[^0-9]%', stuff(@S, 1, charindex('SRN=', @S)+3, '')+' ')-1)
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/104003/

Comment: @Tim It was intended to but was missing a -1 for the return of patindex. Test now.

Comment: No dice, getting a invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function

Comment: I was trying to test against: declare @S varchar(100) = '456 lorem limpsump SRN=123'

Answer (score 1):

Making a GIANT assumption that there is a space at the end of the string you need.

```
declare @str as varchar(100)
set @str='456 lorem limpsump SRN=123 and some more things 3'

--for testing, find the starting point
select charindex('SRN=',@str)

--for testing, find the ending point
select charindex(' ',@str,charindex('SRN=',@str))

--find your substring 
select substring(@str,charindex('SRN=',@str),charindex(' ',@str,charindex('SRN=',@str))-charindex('SRN=',@str))
```

Comment: Works nice, if there is a whitespace, any chance of something that works with/without whitespace?

Comment: @Tim Boland As a human, how can you tell when the thing is over if it isn't because of whitespace? You need to explain how you know that the SRN part of the string is over before asking us how to write code that implements that knowledge.

Comment: @Chris, it would be either whitespace OR end of the field

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... missed that you were just wanting the SRN=12345

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @STRING = '456 lorem limpsump SRN=123456 and some more things 3.'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX('SRN=', @string, 0), CHARINDEX(' ', @string, CHARINDEX('SRN=', @string, 0)) - CHARINDEX('SRN=', @string, 0))
```

Comment: That returns "456 lorem limpsump SRN=123456"

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
with t as(
select '456 lorem limpsump SRN=12378 and some more things 3.' as col )

select substring(col,charindex('SRN=',col)+4,
charindex(' ',col,charindex('SRN=',col))-charindex('SRN=',col)-4)
from t
```